# RadGrid Filter is showing error

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgridview

In RadGrid filter , i am using

```
  CurrentFilterFunction="Contains",AutoPostBackOnFilter="true"
```

Every thing is fine , But one issue I've noticed is that if the user types in the the filter text box and then clicks on the menu to select another option, the default filter is immediately applied, and what i have chosen option from menu that is not opening.
And also i don't want use "FilterDelay" because it is filtering automatically after time interval.

Here i want, When Press on Enter or Tab Buttons filter should work and when user type some text in filter textbox next click on any option from menu that will open.

Can any one give solution?
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically with RadGrid and filtering you can't have it both ways. If you define both `CurrentFilterFunction` and  set `AutoPostBackOnFilter` to true. You can't expect the filtering menu to work the way you want to. That is because `AutoPostBackOnFilter` will rebind the grid when the filter textbox loses focus (if the value has changed), so if you change the value of the filter textbox and then you want to select a different filter function(using the filtering menu) the grid will refresh before you get to select an item from the filtering menu. What you can do is...

1. Keep the `CurrentFilterFunction`, set the `AutoPostBackOnFilter` to `true` and then set `ShowFilterIcon` to false so that users can NOT select a different filtering function, or...
2. Keep the `CurrentFilterFunction`, set the `AutoPostBackOnFilter` to `false` and then set `ShowFilterIcon` to `true` so that users are able to select a different filtering function but notice that you will be dropping a functionality here as well...users will have to MANUALLY select a filtering function in order to filter the grid rather than pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

As mentioned, you can't enable both `AutoPostBackOnFilter` and the filter icon at the same time otherwise you will get exactly these unexpected results